# (Windows) Open the same file simultaneously

Tags: c++, c, windows

I am trying to open a file for writing and reading simultaneously, in windows.
I have one program which writes (every one second) to the file and one that reads from it. In unix it works prefectly but it doesn't work in windows (I can't open an already opened file).
I open the file with fopen().

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT2:**

check out [`_fsopen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f30b0db%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) it uses `FILE *`, and set the share flag accordingly.

**EDIT:**

First of all, some code: this is how I used to open the file

```
   FILE* f = NULL;
        int res = fopen_s(&f, "c:\\temp\\File1.txt", "w");
        if (res != 0) return;

        while (true) {
            Sleep(1000);
            fprintf_s(f , "Some data");
        }
        fclose(f);
```

The read was in other applicaiton, but it did `fscanf` instead.

The fixed code:

```
char d[] = "data";


HANDLE h = CreateFile("c:\\temp\\f.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
    FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, /*FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL*/ FILE_FLAG_WRITE_THROUGH, NULL);

if (h == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return 0;

DWORD bytesW;
while(true) {
    Sleep(100);
        WriteFile(h, d, strlen(d), &bytesW, NULL);
}

CloseHandle(h);
return 0;
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11566930/can-i-allow-multiple-programs-to-read-from-the-same-file-at-the-same-time

Comment: Maybe add simple example (like just open and sleep) programs which work on unix, so it's then easier for somebody to do Win code doing the same.

Comment: Please show code.  A quick test on VS 2008 through VS 2012 indicates that there's no problem with using `fopen()` to open a file for writing and reading at the same time (`fopen()` uses `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` access).

Comment: Hi, I'm going to post some code soon and to answer the question... Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Windows and Linux have a default way of opening a file, which `fopen` uses by default.

In Windows, that means blocking (only one process can open a file at a time).

In Linux, it means non-blocking.

`fopen` is a high-level API. To choose yourself the blocking policy on the file, for Windows you should use [OpenFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from WinAPI. In particular, have a look at the `OF_SHARE_*` flags.

Comment: This answer isn't correct - `fopen()` on Windows opens the file with sharing permitted.

Comment: Wasn't OpenFile the ancient function that was replaced by CreateFile?

Comment: I haven't done Windows programming in the last 4 years or so :-\. OpenFile is one of the Windows APIs I remember the details of, but it may have been deprecated.