# C language, reading own source file and editing source file

Tags: c, fopen

I am currently working on a project which involves reading its own source code, editing it, then recompiling it. My question is how does the fopen function actually work? Is it affected when the source file calling it is open?

I have currently already written a function which reads in and finds the areas in the source code that I have to edit. When I open my source file I am able to read it in, store it in memory, iterate through it, and find what I need. The problem is when I attempt to check if the area to edit is correct through a strcmp function call nothing happens even though it is exact (I have accounted for newlines etc.).

When I copy the source code to another .c file, and have my program read that file instead (an exact copy) it works perfectly fine. I am really confused why that file works and why my source code file does not. They are exactly the same file.

Comment: People can't really give useful answers unless you show your code.

Comment: It shouldn't matter what file you read. The compiled binary that's executing is completely disconnected from the source file.

Comment: Thank you, I am unable to post my code due to the nature of the assignment but that clears up one error that could happen with the source file.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using windows, then beware that [a file can usually only be open in a single process at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757023/windows-open-the-same-file-simultaneously).

So if the source file you are trying to open is already opened in your IDE, you may not be able to open in in your program using `fopen`.