# append and read one file at same time

Tags: c++, c

I have one file that is updated in every second, I append some line end of it and another thread read it every time. so I have two pointer to this file for these work. is it possible?
(I use two while(1) for updating and reading in two function)

thanks.

Comment: I personally would use a lock so that each of the threads are NOT trying to read/write the same file simultaneously. Not because I believe that the actual reading/writing will go wrong, but because you may for example read an incomplete last section of the file, which isn't particularly great.... [Make sure you flush or close the file before releasing the lock when writing, so the content is actually in the FILE, not in some buffer in the C/C++ runtime]

Comment: I do same work but it seems that file doesn't have enough time to write...

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example for reading a **single file** with **multiple threads** : [Mutlitple thread reading a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823479/multiple-threads-reading-from-the-same-file)
You could start from here.

Like said @MatsPetersson, you have to be really sure of what you're doing in each thread. If you don't want to read incomplete data, you will need to make sure the other thread is not writing in the file. There's several ways of doing this, you can use for example `Mutex` or `Signal` or `Shared Memory Segment of a bool`.

I think in your case, even if it's not explicit, you need to **read only when no other thread is writing**, to do this I will recommand the use of `Mutex`. Here's the doc : [Mutex function documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex) .

So we have `readThread` and `writeThread`. Here's a pseudo-code of how you treat your problem :

```
    main(){
         putTheMutexTo(1);
    }

    readThread(){
         consumeMutex(1);
         openTheFile();
         readTheFile();
         closeTheFile();
         loadMutex(1);
    }

    writeThread(){
         consumeMutex(1);
         openTheFile();
         writeTheFile();
         closeTheFile();
         loadMutex(1);
    }
```

But if you don't really know how `Mutex` works, **don't go code right now**, and [go read some doc on the Internet](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/05/c-mutex-examples/), because this is a bit complex to understand when you start.