# Conditional Thread Making

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, pthreads

I made this problem by myself!

I'm reading a file, in `C`, where each line contains a number (random between 0 to 1000000):

```
1121
84
928434
9999
70373
...
```

I read line by line, and for each line, I do some calculation and write a big chuck of data into a file named `d_file.txt` where `d` is the list significant digit of the read number. Assume writing in file takes a long time, so I want to write a the code in a `multi-thread` so I can write in multiple files (~10) at the same time. While the `single thread` `C` code is obvious, I'm wondering how `multi-thread` code using `pthread` looks like.

`single-thread` C code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int func(int a)
{
        //assume the data is big and writing takes a long time
        int data = a;
        return data;
}
int main()
{
        ifstream in("numbers.txt");
        int a;
        while(in >> a)
        {
                stringstream ss;
                ss << a%10;
                string str;
                ss >> str;
                str += "_File.txt";
                ofstream out(str.c_str(), fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
                //This is blocking, if write takes long
                //but can be rewritten in a multi-thread fashion
                // to allow upto 10 simultaneous file write
                out << func(a) << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Needs some edits -- wrote in rush.

Comment: Multiple threads will not speed this program up.  You'll be just as I/O bound with 10 threads as with one, probably more so due to the additional head-seeking overhead.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner what about if I use fwrite()?

Comment: fwrite() won't make much difference either.  You're limited by the speed of your hard drive -- no matter how efficiently the CPU is operating, the data won't be placed onto the hard drive faster than the hard drive can accept it.  The only way to speed it up would be to get a faster hard drive (e.g. an SSD?), or each output file to a separate drive, or (fastest of all) don't write to the hard drive at all (instead just store the results in RAM).

Answer (score -1):

You can definitely read a file, and multiple sections of a file, at the same time. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/823479/multiple-threads-reading-from-the-same-file) SO answer. If that isn't enough for you there are lots more on SO and across the web explaining how to both read and write to ASCII in parallel.

Comment: More comment than answer. Possible suggestion for a duplicate?

Comment: Still answers his question.