# Using multiple threads to read and write the same file without mmap?

Tags: c, multithreading, file, thread-safety, mmap

Related: [Multiple threads reading from the same file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/823479)

mmap can be used to read and write files, but it does not support large files, for example, on a 32-bit system.

The stdio FILE* in C, or linux file handles, on the other hand, can handle big files, except that they come with a position inside the file obtained by `ftell`. This means that, even for read operations, we cannot use the same file handler in multiple threads (without locks). If one creates multiple handles, the writes might not be possible to proceed safely in parallel.

Is there a nice way to overcome the disadvantage of both methods above, for large files to be accessed by multiple threads in parallel (with writes on disjoint blocks)?

Of course, sometimes it is impossible not to use locks. But ideally, it would be nice to have a method to read from storage devices without unnecessary locks, in the case where the storage device supports parallel access.

Comment: 32-bit systems in general can't handle files larger than 2GB.

Comment: Is this a read-only file?

Comment: For reads of an unchanging file you can read the file in multiple threads without issue. Just open and close the file in each thread separately. For writes, to avoid data corruption and performance hits due to locking, then where the application permits it, you can make each thread work on its own partition the file only. By partition, I mean some contiguous interval of offsets of the file data. I don't think you can safely insert data this way, but you can update existing data and append in at most one thread.

Comment: If you use the low-level system call interface `open()` to open the file, you can use `pread()` and `pwrite()` to access data at specified offsets without affecting the current seek position. For 32-bit systems, compile with `-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64` for large file support.

Comment: @SimonGoater Do you mean using multiple file handles to write or just a single handle?

Comment: Yes, multiple file handles. I don't know if it would be okay to open them all in the parent first, but when I do it I open them in each thread separately and that works.

Comment: @Barmar, 32-bit systems can well handle files larger than 2GiB. For glibc/Linux, see `__USE_FILE_OFFSET64`, for example. I know that the 32-bit Windows API can also handle files larger than 2GiB.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. Open the file once for each thread, either via `fopen()` to get a `FILE*` or via `open()` to get a file descriptor. Then each of your threads can safely read from and write to the same file in parallel, as long, as each thread uses its private file descriptor for this.
2. Only do a single `open()` and then use `pread()` and `pwrite()` for reading and writing. As these do neither access nor update the seek position, they can be safely used from different threads on the same file descriptor.

Of course, in both cases, you have to make sure, that while one thread is writing a certain region of the file, no other thread is reading that same region or also writing to it, or you risk to get corrupted data.